# datatables export html table into excel in differents sheets group by date

Tags: jquery, excel, datatables

I would like to make a button to export a HTML table into differents sheets.
For example: I have a table contains dates column.

```
name  | date
Hamza | 2018/04/25
...   | 2018/04/26
...   | ...
...   | 2018/04/30
john  | 2018/06/05
```

I want to make data of 1st week (25/04=>30) on a sheet and other week on another

Comment: Is it an HTML table or a jQuery DataTable?

Comment: jquery datatable

Answer (score 0):

The way to get the data from a jQuery DataTable is to use `$([table]).DataTable().rows().data()`.

That will give you each line of your table as an array of arrays. Using your example, it should return:

`[["Hamza", "2018/04/25],["", 2018/04/26],["",""]["", 2018/04/30],["john", "2018/06/05"]]`

Now that you have that, you can cycle through your data with a `.forEach` and select whatever you want. As to creating a spreadsheet from it, the best way is to create a .csv from the data. Putting it all together should look something like this:

```
const tableData = $([table]).DataTable().rows().data();
let csv = '';
tableData.forEach( rowArray => {
  if (rowArray[1] === '2018/04/25') csv += rowArray.join(",") + "\r\n" )
};
```